# PowerColor AMD/ATI Radeon HD5450 compatibility with intel 915 boards

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard

I am thinking to buy PowerColor AMD/ATI Radeon HD5450 Graphics card because i am not able to smoothly play HD videos as well as game.
I don't want to upgrade the machine cause it work well n performance is good.

PC Hardware :-
Motherboard : Intel 915 Gvwb
RAM : 1Gb DDR
Processor : Intel 2.6 Ghz

Does this card support's my pc hardware?
This card is 64 bit and DDR3. And my RAM is DDR i have PCI slot where i can plug the TV tuner. Does this card will fit into same? or PCI-E is needed? Does my board have it? Please help.

Comment: Run CPU-Z or other tools and look for the complete Motherboard name. 915 is only the chipset name. The 915 was the first to support PCIe.But I think it makes no sense. Your hardware is too old. Buy an AMD system with a Trinity APU (CPU+GPU).

Comment: If your motherboard doesn't have a PCI-E slot, you can forget about buying this card.

Comment: @magicandre1981 - i think adding a Graphic card will solve at least hd video playback issue cause mostly now videos are 720p.

Comment: @WeloSefer it has PCI-E slot

Comment: Well, as @magicandre1981 has said you hardware is old but if you insist on buying it, you just have to make sure you have 350 W Power Supply or greater. As long as, you motherboard has a free PCI-E slot.

Comment: @WeloSefer hmm i think it has 350W power supply but i am not sure about PCI and PCI-E but in manual of motherboard they said it has. So do you think DDR3 graphic's card will match the FSB  of board and my RAM?

Comment: Have you figured out which motherboard yo use?

Comment: @magicandre1981 i use intel 915GVWB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  [intel 915GVWB motherboard only supports PCIe x1](http://downloadmirror.intel.com/15191/eng/D915GVWB_ProductGuide01_English.pdf) (see figure 1 on page 11), and so you **CAN'T install** a PCIe graphic card into it. They ll require a PCIe x16 slot.

Buy a new system with an AMD Trinity (which includes a GPU inside the CPU), 4GB RAM (which is cheap today) and you have a system which is ok for watching HD videos.

Comment: Minor point - if its an open backed slot, or by using a extender which may need some minor mods, you can put a PCIe card into a 1x slot - there's some [examples here](http://blog.zorinaq.com/?e=42) - Apparently PCIe goes down to lower modes gracefully, even If I don't suggest the extreme step of [card surgery](http://www.invisiblerobot.com/pcie_x1/). Its a horrible idea (unless the board has an open backed slot, and this is an interim measure - in which case it might work), but it may be possible

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Impressed by your comment it seems a cool idea to try out, i'll surely try this only when i am sure that i dont need my machine anymore. :) Thanks i never thought people do such RND in hardware also. Great job man. Nice To meet you. :)